# Height average between 4 points

Tags: geometry

I have a $3D$ space, if I had a square in this space:

```
square = {{ 0, 0, 100}, { 100, 100, 50}, { 0, 100, 22}, { 100, 0, 86}};
```

how could I get the average height of any point in this field where `0 < x < 100` and `0 < y < 100`?

For example I want the `z` value on `x == 40 && y == 33`.

Comment: yes, probably you didn't understand my question correctly, i don't want the distance between points, i want to generate a 'height' for given x,y points if i knew the heights for 0,0 100,0 0,100 and 100,100

Comment: Do you want to interpolate a z-value between those points?

Comment: `Plot3D[Interpolation[{{0, 0, 100}, {0, 100, 22}, {100, 100, 50}, {100, 0, 86}}, {x, y}, InterpolationOrder -> 1], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation):

```
f = Interpolation[square, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
f[40, 33]//N
(* 74.204 *)
```

Comment: Exactly ! the image on wikipedia looks just like what i am doing ... now the problem is to convert that to a code ... thanks :)